# Disable inverse scrolling on trackpad?

Tags: touchpad, 16.10

I just can't get use to inverse/natural scrolling or whatever it is.

How do I disable the system wide inverse scrolling and go back to the more traditional scrolling?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is launch settings app, click on "Mouse & Touchpad", then you'll see the "Natural scrolling" at the bottom, toggle that, then click "Test Your Settings" and make sure it works.

I hope that helps!

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to change it...:-(

Comment: Weird, it could be a bug, especially considering you're using 16.10, which is a pre-release, did you try rebooting after changing that setting?

Comment: Don't know, but 16.10 is not pre-release, it is officially out...but I suppose it could be a bug...I guess I will wait for some updates and see what happens.